# Center align text for wonky UA fonts

Tags: css, fonts

Is there a way to align the default monospace font vertically within a container consistently across browsers even if it has wonky descender spacing like Nimbus Mono PS shown below?
I want to use the default monospace on a user's computer and mine for some reason had nimbus mono ps, which I've since changed.

Devtools screencap:

[image: devtool screencap]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  2
</div>
```

Attempt 1: Magic number padding - works on my machine ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  padding-block-start: 0.3em;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  2
</div>
```

Attempt 2: Vertical align/line height - doesn't seem to work

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cell {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: gold;
}

.cell span {
  line-height: 1ch;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `place-items`...Zach...

Comment: @RenevanderLende Hey Rene  that doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Didn't you just forget about the extra space consumption by `padding` without `* { box-sizing: border-box }`?

Comment: Oh I'll add the box sizing to the snippets, I have it on my machine and doesn't fix

Comment: With `border-box` I would expect the second option to be as large as 1 and 3, but the text moved down '0.3em' (from center). Which it does in Ch/Ed/FF on my W10-x64. My [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/JjBqzqz)

Comment: yea see on my machine x64 linux firefox and brave that's centered, so it's not consistent is the issue. Must be the locally installed font on windows vs linux?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251740/discussion-between-zach-jensz-and-rene-van-der-lende).

Comment: Browser was using Nimbus Mono PS as default monospace font, changed that out and it's fixed